# Some Extra Space in the beginning of second line

Tags: minipage

Refer what i have done so far.
Question: Very simple question why there is some extra blank space in the starting of the second line indicated by red below arrows.
I have already asked this question and our two users helped me lot,[image] but still the problem is not fully solved.
Please tell me where is the problem. i am very Inquisitive about it.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{ }
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\large
\noindent This is the first line. And why there is some blanks space between the first and second line \\ 
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
In $\triangle{ABC}$ $\angle B = 90^{\circ}$,\\
By using Pythagoras Theorem,
\begin{align*}
AC^2&=AB^2+BC^2& \tag{$*$}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\flushright
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzDefPoint(0:0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(0:5){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(90:4){C}

    \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.6mm](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.8mm](B){$B$}

    \tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](B,A)
    \tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,A)

    \tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap,rotate=-38.5,xshift=-15mm,yshift=0mm](A,C){Hypotenuse}
    \tkzLabelSegment[auto,rotate=0,xshift=0.3mm,yshift=-0.7mm](A,B){Adjacent Side}
    \tkzLabelSegment[auto,rotate=90,xshift=15.3mm,yshift=3.8mm](B,C){Opposite Side}

    %% here use the correct order. For example, BCA is inner angle and ACB is outer angle
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0cm,color=red,mark=](C,A,B)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=black,mark=](C,A,B)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(C,B,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.4](C,A,B){$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}  \\  
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of your previous question? the text in the  vertical centre of the minipages are in line and the one on the right is larger.

Comment: Sir, still problem is unsolved.

Comment: If you add a `[b]` optional parameter to the first minipage (`\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}`), they get top-aligned. However, there is still a little space left between the lines, but maybe that's enough for you.

Comment: any other way to reduce space.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\begin{minipage}[t]`, with `\vspace{0pt}` at the top of the minipage containing the picture. Finish off with `\medskip`.

I've made a few changes in the definitions of headers and footers; I also added `headheight=14.5pt` as requested by `fancyhdr`.

I can't recommend using `\large` at the beginning. If you want 14pt size (but it's *really* big), load the `extarticle` class with the `14pt` option (and set `headheight` as `fancyhdr` will recommend).

Don't use `\flushright` (which starts an environment, but in a wrong way): in this case `\raggedleft` is the right command. Oh, and don't use `\\` for ending paragraphs: *never ever*.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  left=0.7in,
  right=0.7in,
  headheight=14.5pt,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

This is the first line. And why there is some blanks space between the first and second line

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
In $\triangle{ABC}$ $\angle B = 90^{\circ}$.

By using Pythagoras' Theorem,
\begin{align*}
AC^2&=AB^2+BC^2& \tag{$*$}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt} % to anchor the minipage at the very top
\raggedleft
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzDefPoint(0:0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(0:5){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(90:4){C}

    \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.6mm](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below,yshift=-0.8mm](B){$B$}

    \tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](B,A)
    \tkzDrawSegment[black!60!black](C,A)

    \tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap,rotate=-38.5,xshift=-15mm,yshift=0mm](A,C){Hypotenuse}
    \tkzLabelSegment[auto,rotate=0,xshift=0.3mm,yshift=-0.7mm](A,B){Adjacent Side}
    \tkzLabelSegment[auto,rotate=90,xshift=15.3mm,yshift=3.8mm](B,C){Opposite Side}

    %% here use the correct order. For example, BCA is inner angle and ACB is outer angle
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0cm,color=red,mark=](C,A,B)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=black,mark=](C,A,B)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(C,B,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.4](C,A,B){$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}

\medskip

Some text after the picture.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir. Thanks how can I express I don't know but really this is great help to me.  I learn some new thing from answer

Comment: For ending paragraph which is the easiest and ideal way

Comment: @snehal A blank line